# C++x0 unique_ptr GCC 4.4.4

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I am trying to make use of the unique_ptr from C++x0, by  doing

```
#include <memory>
```

and comping with  -std=c++0x, however it is throwing up many errors this being an example.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/bits/unique_ptr.h:214: error: deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>&) [with _Tp = Descriptor, _Tp_Deleter = std::default_delete<Descriptor>]’
```

UPDATE****
This is what I am trying to do, I have removed typedefs so you can see clearly the types

```
static std::unique_ptr<SomeType> GetSomeType()
{
    std::unique_ptr<SomeType> st("Data","Data2",false);

    std::unique_ptr<OtherType> ot("uniportantconstructor data");

    st->Add(ot);

    return st;

}

//Public method of SomeType
  void Add(std::unique_ptr<OtherType> ot)
  {
    //otmap is std::map<std::string,std::unique_ptr<OtherType> >
    //mappair is std::Pair<std::string,std::unique_ptr<OtherType> >
     otMap.Insert(mappair(ot->name(),ot)); 
  }
```

UPDATE:

If my class SomeType has a method that returns a element from the map (using the key) say

```
std::unique_ptr<OtherType> get_othertype(std::string name)
{
   return otMap.find(name);
}
```

that would enure the caller would recieve a pointer to the one in the map rather than a copy?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `unique_ptr` does not have an `Add` method. Do you mean `st->Add` by any chance?

Comment: Yeah I fixed it sorry, typed this from memory not compiled it or anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::unique_ptr<OtherType> ot("unimportant constructor data");
st->Add(ot);
```

You cannot pass an lvalue to a function accepting a `unique_pointer`, because `unique_pointer` has no copy constructor. You must either move the lvalue (to cast it to an xvalue) or pass a prvalue:

```
// pass an xvalue:
std::unique_ptr<OtherType> ot("unimportant constructor data");
st->Add(std::move(ot));
// note: ot is now empty

// pass a prvalue:
st->Add(std::unique_ptr<OtherType>("unimportant constructor data"));
```

Inside the `Add` method, things are a little more complicated. First, you have to move from `ot`, because formal parameters are always lvalues (since they have names). Second, you cannot move from `ot` and get `ot->name()` as arguments to the `mappair` function, because the order of argument evaluation is unspecified in C++. So we have to get `ot->name()` in a separate statement before moving from `ot`:

```
void Add(std::unique_ptr<OtherType> ot)
{
    auto name = ot->name();
    otMap.Insert(mappair(name, std::move(ot))); 
}
```

Hope this helps. Note that under no (sane) circumstances can two `unique_ptr` objects point to the same thing. If you need that functionality, `unique_ptr` is not what you want.

Comment: don't forget to include `<utility>` to get `std::move`

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to use the copy constructor. There isn't one. If your calling code looks like this:

```
T *ptr = /* whatever */;
std::unique_ptr<T> up = ptr;
```

You have to change the second line to this:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> up (ptr);
```

The original version is (basically) implicitly turning the assignment into:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> up (std::unique_ptr<T>(ptr));
```

The copy constructor has been deleted. "deleted function" is C++0x-speak for explicitly removing an implicit special member function. In this case, the copy constructor.

Comment: Thanks, and that explanation of the error should help in the future.

Comment: Does this mean I cant pass unique_ptr as a parameter or return it from a function?

Comment: @Mark: No, to both.  But you have to do so using the move constructor, rather than the copy constructor.  For instance, `function(std::move(pointer));`

Comment: I am surprised that gcc didn't invoke the move constructor instead of the copy constructor in this case. Could it be a bug or just not implemented yet?

Comment: I was just guessing about your code; how about posting a snippet?

Comment: Seems overly complex, I have went back to shared_ptr, much easier.

Comment: @Mark: They just have completely different meaning. `unique_ptr` means that the object will not be shared with other pointers. Where transfer of ownership is implicit with `auto_ptr`, you have to be explicit with `unique_ptr`, except where rules concerning rvalue references kick in (such as returning a local `unique_ptr` by value).

Comment: The problem here is not a nonexisting copy constructor but simply that the constructor that takes a pointer is `explicit`. `explicit` constructors are basically ignored in the copy initialization syntax. Note that "copy initialization" doesn't imply copying but may involve a move construction. Your first and third example will compile if you make the constructor taking a ptr implicit.

Comment: See my update with code example of what I am trying to achieve, Thanks for the input so far though, appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As @Steve said you're probably using the copy constructor, `unique_ptr` does not support copy semantics, if you want to **move** to value to another `unique_ptr` you're have to `move` it.

```
 unique_ptr<T> other = std::move(orig); // orig is now null
```