# C++ unique_ptr and map

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, stl, unique-ptr

I'm trying to use the [C++0x](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) [`unique_ptr` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee410601.aspx) inside a [`map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) like so:

```
// compile with `g++ main.cpp -std=gnu++0x`

#include <string.h>    
#include <map>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct Foo {
    char *str;    
    Foo(char const *str_): str(strdup(str_)) {}
};

int main(void) {
    typedef std::map<int, unique_ptr<Foo>> Bar;
    Bar bar;
    auto a = bar.insert(Bar::value_type(1, new Foo("one")));
    return 0;
}
```

However GCC gives me the following error (shortened, I think this is the relevant part, please test on your own C++ compiler):

```
main.cpp:19:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/unique_ptr.h:214: error: deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr&) [with _Tp = Foo, _Tp_Deleter = std::default_delete]’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_pair.h:68: error: used here
```

I'm really not sure what I've done wrong, this works on MSVC. I have found very [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763621/cx0-unique-ptr-gcc-4-4-4) questions, that seem alike, however their solutions do not work for me.

```
matt@stanley:/media/data/src/c++0x-test$ gcc --version
gcc-4.4.real (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3
```

Comment: Not the answer, but Foo should have a destructor that frees str because strdup mallocs memory and copies str_ into that memory.

Comment: It's C++0x no matter when it is officially published. As Stroustrup put it, think of x as a hexadecimal :)

Comment: @Loy Franco: Yeah I know, that would be next to implement, but I never made it this far (it's a simplified extract of a larger problem I'm having).

Comment: You should add a destructor Foo::~Foo that frees the memory and explicitly disable any copying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to correctly use `unique_ptr` in a `map::insert` yet. Here's the GCC bug for it:

[Bug 44436 - [C++0x] Implement `insert(&&)` and `emplace*` in associative and unordered containers](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44436)

It looks like it may be [fixed for GCC 4.6](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html), but it won't build from SVN on vanilla Ubuntu 10.04.1 to confirm.

### Update0

This is not working as of GCC svn r165422 (4.6.0).

Comment: The code in question works with GCC 4.6.1 with a minor change (added an explicit conversion to `unique_ptr<Foo>`).

Answer (score 28):

First: Your class Foo is really a very bad approximation of std::string. I predict lots of memory leaks. (Search for "rule of three".)

Second: A pointer is not implicitly convertible to a unique_ptr object (for safety reasons). But the templated pair constructor requires the arguments to be *implicitly* convertible to the respective value types. GCC seems to allow this but it is a bug. You have to create the unique_ptr object manually. Unfortunately the C++0x draft lacks the following, very useful function template that eases the creation of temporary unique_ptr objects. It's also exception-safe:

```
template<class T, class...Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args)
{
    std::unique_ptr<T> ret (new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    return ret;
}
```

In addition, let's use the new *emplace* function instead of *insert*:

```
auto a = bar.emplace(1,make_unique<Foo>("one"));
```

*emplace* forwards both arguments to the corresponding pair constructor.

The actual problem you witnessed is that the pair constructor tried to copy a unique_ptr even though such an object is only "movable". It seems that GCC's C++0x support is not yet good enough to handle this situation correctly. From what I can tell, my line from above should work according to the current standard draft (N3126).

**Edit:** I just tried the following as a workaround using GCC 4.5.1 in experimental C++0x mode:

```
map<int,unique_ptr<int> > themap;
themap[42].reset(new int(1729));
```

This is also supposed to work in the upcoming standard but GCC rejects it as well. Looks like you have to wait for GCC to support unique_ptr in maps and multimaps.

Comment: @Matt: Well, there's nothing *I* can do about it. std::unique_ptr as mapped type in a map is supposed to work. GCC can't handle that yet. You could file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. When support is added in GCC, I'll be able to test it and give +1!

Comment: I just ran into this as well.  Thanks for the detailed write-up.  Saved me a lot of head-scratching.

Comment: this seems to be a problem in `Clang 3.6.2` as well

Answer (score 1):

I've just been tinkering with unique_ptr in gcc 4.6.0. Here's some (very ugly) code which works correctly:

```
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<int> > table;
table.insert(std::pair<int, std::unique_ptr<int>>(15, std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(42))));
table[2] = std::move(table[15]);
for (auto& i : table)
{
    if (i.second.get())
        printf("%d\n", *i.second);
    else
    {
        printf("empty\n");
        i.second.reset(new int(12));
    }
}
printf("%d\n", *table[15]);
```

The output is 42, empty, 12 - so apparently it works. As far as I can tell, the only 'problem' is that awful looking insert command. 'emplace' isn't implemented in gcc 4.6.0

Comment: +1 At least insert and the pair's conversion constructor seems to be working as intended (conversion since `value_type` is `pair<const int,....`) But there is still slight issue w.r.t. exception safety. In general, dynamically allocating an object and initializing a unique_ptr with that pointer should be consecutive actions. But C++ does not guarantee in which order subexpressions are evaluated. That's why I used make_unique as a function call. This way, there are two extra sequence points.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `emplace` method of map.