# Create std::pair or std::map with std::unique_ptr as value implicitely

Tags: c++11, stdmap, std-pair

This code works in Visual Studio:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
} data_t;

using datap_t = std::unique_ptr<data_t>;
using MyPair = std::pair<std::string, datap_t>;

int main() {
    data_t * pd1 = new data_t();
    MyPair p("tst", pd1); // This does not compile in gcc or clang
    // MyPair p2("tst", datap_t(pd1)); // This compiles

    return 0;
}
```

But clang and gcc give error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<data_t> >::pair(const char [3], data_t*&)
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/35w1pN) is the ideone to try.

The fact that I can call `datap_t(pd1)` and it compiles means the constructor is valid, so why is that template does not find a suitable match?

I was looking to add a key-value pair to a map using emplace and that is why I wanted to have this implicit conversion in the first place. Note that like Visual Studio the implicit conversion works for most other types, such as `std::string` from `"raw string"`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3906685/311567) looks relevant, but it talks about a fixed bug and is very old.

Comment: Don't use raw pointers. `auto pd1 = std::make_unique<data_t>()`.

Comment: @kfsone I do not, when dealing with external C libraries dealing with raw pointers is inevitable. Also, I am interested to see why this works in Visual Studio and not clang, not looking for how to make it work :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `std::unique_ptr` constructor that take a single raw pointer as input is marked as `explicit` to prevent implicit conversions.

`pd1` is a raw pointer.  `MyPair p("tst", pd1);` involves an implicit conversion to `std::unique_ptr`, which is why the compile fails in Clang and GCC, as it should be.  You have to use an explicit conversion instead:

```
MyPair p("tst", datap_t(pd1));
```

A better option is to not use the raw pointer at all:

```
MyPair p("tst", std::make_unique<data_t>());
```

Clang and GCC are doing the right thing, Visual Studio is not (despite its [`unique_ptr` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee475591.aspx) showing the relevant constructor is `explicit`).